# How do I override the OK/Cancel button of new list item form in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, navigation

I have a custom list in SharePoint, and I want to override the OK/Cancel buttons that are in the New Item form (The form displayed when you click "New" in the default view of the list).

I want the saving logic to remain intact, but I just want to change the default page it redirects to, ideally, to a whole separate page on the site that's not a view of the list.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking for, a programmatic approach would be to write an Event Handler and after the ItemUpdated or ItemAdded event redirect to the location you want.

For more information

[Ted Pattison MSDN Article on Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163318.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. [I guessing you are working with list]

- Navigate to NewForm.aspx of that particular list
- Open it for editing
- Go to Data view Controls and drop Form action control to the form
- Add Commit and navigate to page actions in sequence.